# Como requisitar arquivo de outra pasta e executa-lo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou fazendo um bot para o discord, ai tem uma pasta chamada commands, queria saber como chamo os arquivos dessa pasta no meu arquivo principal, bot.js e executo eles

Comment: Nem vim esse post, tbm não entendi a resposta dele

Answer (score 1):

```
meu-app
   |--bot.js // Arquivo principal
   |--commands // Pasta com os comandos que serão executados no arquivo bot.js
     |--index.js
```

---

```
// commands/index.js

module.exports = function check() { 
    return "Estou sendo executado de dentro da pasta commands." 
}
```

Considerando que o arquivo bot.js e a pasta commands estão no mesmo nível de diretório, para chamar o arquivo index.js que está dentro da pasta commands, no arquivo bot.js use o comando require para chamar os arquivos da pasta commands.

```
// bot.js
const check = require('./commands');
console.log(check());
// Estou sendo executado de dentro da pasta commands.
```